# CCheckListBox items get overlapped on selection if app build using 'Visual Studio 2017 (v141)' Platform Toolset

Tags: c++, mfc

Currently trying to use CCheckListBox control into a project.
The project is a simple MFC Dialog based application.
Into the dialog added List Box control with below specific property.

```
 Owner Draw -> Fixed
 Selection -> Multiple
 Has String -> True
```

Added below variable into header using Class Wizard

```
CCheckListBox mCheckListBox;
```

Added below item into source file.

```
mCheckListBox.AddString(L"Item-1");
mCheckListBox.AddString(L"Item-2");
mCheckListBox.AddString(L"Item-3");
mCheckListBox.AddString(L"Item-4");
```

Once the app build using Platform Toolset 'Visual Studio 2012 (v110)', the app works without issues.
But if build the app using Platform Toolset 'Visual Studio 2017 (v141)', the list item gets overlapped on selection.

If there is anyone face the same, please share the solution.
It will be highly appreciated.

Note:
If there is same question available, please share the link.

Comment: Why do you have owner-draw set? Owner drawn controls are where you inherit an MFC control and implement the `DrawItem` to get a custom look and feel. Which you're not doing by simply using CCheckListBox. Switch it off and see if behaviour changes.

Comment: I've seen the overlapping entries, too. No solution, yet, sorry.

Comment: @acraig5075 `CCheckListBox` does require the owner-draw flag (it's a custom look-and-feel control implemented by MFC).

Comment: @acraig5075 Thanks for your comment. As you know Owner-Draw has three option (No, Fixed, Variable). I have tried both No and Variable. The app get crashed.

Comment: @j6t Thank for your confirmation.
Is this issue fixed into Platform toolset v142 (Visual Studio 2019)?

Comment: @gsmaker  Can't tell, I'm still on v141.

Comment: Could you post a picture that shows the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's another MFC bug.

You can circumvent this bug by adding this somewhere in the `OnInitDialog` method:

```
mCheckListBox.SetFont(GetFont());
```

Comment: I think this bug shows up when system DPI is 125% or more, but application is not DPI aware.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani on my platform (WIndows 10) it shows up at 100% DPI as well.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you very much. I have confirmed that adding above line fix the issue.